# Remove pip and then install pip3 in python3.x

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have made a mistake.
I have following [this instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).
Now i want to remove pip and then reinstall pip3.

Comment: I would recommend checking out [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu, why not just use `apt` or `apt-get`?

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` - to install pip3

`sudo apt-get remove python3-pip`- to remove pip

Assuming you installed pip for python3, not python.

**Edit:**

You should specify if you installed pip using Linux package manager or using script (get-pip.py)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

> you need to execute the following command to install pip sudo apt-get
>   install python3-pip
>
> and to remove you need to use sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
>   python3-pip